# SBTableAlert Crash

Tags: objective-c, ios

This is driving me insane!

I've tried implementing the alertview with table view exactly as the demo application does. However, on mine it crashes with: 
*** -[SBTableAlert tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1e0aa800

I'm aware why this is doing it, i just cannot seem to trace it or fix it. Also inexplicable why my version doesn't work when the demo apps version does. UNless I am missing something obvious.

My implementation:

```
 SBTableAlert *alert = [[SBTableAlert alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"contact_deleted_title", NULL) cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"contact_deleted_cancel_button_title", NULL) messageFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"contact_deleted_message", NULL)];
    [alert setType:SBTableAlertTypeMultipleSelct];
    [alert.view addButtonWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"contact_deleted_other_button_title", NULL)];
    [alert.view setTag:0];
    [alert setDataSource:self];
    [alert setDelegate:self];
    [alert show];
```

For the purpose of debugging my delegate method implementations are copy and pasted directly from the sample app and the SBTableAlert.h/m are untouched.

HELP!

Comment: No. Can't remember what I did in lieu. Was an old project.

Comment: @CW007007 no worries. I got it working. I posted what worked for me below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem; the solution outlined below fixed it:

**Step 1 :** Add `SBTableAlert.h` and `SBTableAlert.m` to your project. This class uses MRC.

**Step 2:** Therefore, Tell `ARC`to exclude the entire class file (the .m), Go to `Target Build Phase`s and in the `Compiler Sources` you add the `-fno-objc-arc` flag as shown in the following figure: http://www.invasivecode.com/blogimages/Xcode/ARC-Fig1.png

**Step 3:** The `message sent to deallocated instance 0x1e0aa800` error is occurring because the `SBTableAlert *alert` is deallocated by `ARC` before the Alert shows.

To make sure it's still around when you need it. Make it a Strong property i.e.
in

```
//
//  YourViewController.h
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SBTableAlert.h"

@interface YourViewController : UITableViewController <SBTableAlertDelegate,     SBTableAlertDataSource>{

@property (strong, nonatomic) SBTableAlert *strongAlert;

}

@end

//
//  YourViewController.m
//

@implementation YourViewController
@synthesize strongAlert;
```

Then your above code (that attempts to display the alert) becomes

```
strongAlert = [[SBTableAlert alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"contact_deleted_title", NULL) cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"contact_deleted_cancel_button_title", NULL) messageFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"contact_deleted_message", NULL)];
[strongAlert setType:SBTableAlertTypeMultipleSelct];
[strongAlert.view addButtonWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"contact_deleted_other_button_title", NULL)];
[strongAlert.view setTag:0];
[strongAlert setDataSource:self];
[strongAlert setDelegate:self];
[strongAlert show];
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You miss [alert autorelease];

If you don't use ARC, the the code above won't work. However, you should not use ARC so the release/autorelease/dealloc must be used due to lack of reference.